# Configurar las librería Boost a un proyecto, C++

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans

He estado buscando librerías para *C++* y me tope con las librerías *Boost* en *C++*.

Descargue la última versión (*boost_1_64_0*). Extraje el *.zip* y están todas las librerías, y toda la documentación. Ahora bien mi pregunta es: *¿Cómo usar su abanico de librerías en un proyecto?*, en mi caso para ser mas especifico uso *Netbeans* en su versión *8.2*, y el compilador que uso son lo s del paquete de *MinGW*. No se en sí qué pasos previos debe hacerse para usarlas en un proyecto o cómo configurarlas para su uso en un proyecto.

Luego de configurarlas ahí si se podria usar el:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
```

Claro sin hacerlo el compilador no reconoce las librerías y tira un error.

**[ACTUALIZACIÓN]**

He intentado hacer lo que me sugirieron en las respuesta, tal como lo dice en la página oficial de *Boost*.

Pero no entiendo porque me dice el siguiente mensaje en la consola de Windows:

```
"cl" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. 

Failed to build Boost.Build engine. 
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics. You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941 

Also, you can file an issue at svn.boost.org Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.
```

**[/ACTUALIZACIÓN]**

Comment: Tal y como te he comentado en mi respuesta, cl es una herramienta del entorno C++ de Visual Studio. Tienes que instalar el entorno C++ de VS para poder instalar la librería Boost de forma automática. Por otro lado si únicamente vas a utilizar librerías de templates no es necesario que instales nada... te basta con añadir las rutas de inclusión correspondientes a tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como reza la [documentación de Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/bbv2.html#bbv2.installation) la tarea se debería resumir en unos sencillos pasos:

1. Descomprimir los ficheros
2. ejecutar un script dependiendo de si estás en Windows (`./bootstrap.bat`) o Linux (`./bootstrap.sh`)
3. Ejecutar `./b2 install --prefix=PREFIX`, donde `PREFIX` es el directorio donde quieres instalar Boost
4. Opcionalmente, añadir `PREFIX\bin` a la variable de entorno del sistema `PATH`

Para más información o dudas te recomiendo leerte la documentación de las librerías ya que ahí se detalla demasiada información como para exponerla alegremente en una respuesta.

Comment: Al ejecutar el scripts me tira un error.

Comment: @CookieRabbit Muy gráfico y explicativo tu comentario...

Comment: Al ejecutar (bootstrap.bat) dentro de la carpeta en el cmd. "cl" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.

Comment: Disculpa por el comentario anterior no ser específico.

Comment: @CookieRabit `cl` es una herramienta de Microsoft que se instala al hacer lo propio con el entorno C++ del Visual Studio. No sé si también se podrá instalar con las librerías de desarrollo de tu versión de Windows